# How to access an isolated Network from a NAT network in QEMU

Tags: networking, nat, bridge, qemu

I have a couple of VMs running on QEMU, some need to access the internet while others should be isolated. I already have two virtual networks, one of type `NAT` and the other is isolated. I want to access the isolated VMs from the VMs in the normal `NAT` network, but it doesn't work by default, how can I fix this?

The kernel routing table looks like this:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.115 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.115 metric 600 
192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Why can't the 192.168.122.0/24 network (NAT'd, not isolated) access the 192.168.100.0/24 (NAT'd, isolated).
My goal is to isolate some VMs from the internet, but not from non isolated VMs.

Comment: You need to decide whether machines should be isolated or connected.  Connecting isolated machine is most always not possible. Simultaneous isolation and connection on the same device is an oxymoron .

Comment: The goal is to block the isolated VMs from accessing the internet not other (non isolated) VMs.

Comment: Still not possible so far as I can see using virtual machines.

Comment: The host can still access the isolated VMs, so I was wondering if I could somehow configure a bridge on the host to redirect traffic.

Comment: I am not sure how you could redirect within a built-in VM APP internal DHCP server with NAT

Comment: Added more details, both bridges are in the kernel routing table but still for some reason I can't access the isolated network.

Comment: You would need to reverse engineer the QEMU NAT app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly a solution, but a workaround since I doubt there is a way to let traffic out of the isolated network:

For the VMs that need to access the isolated network, add a new interface connected to that network. This way you can access the internet over one interface, and the isolated network over the other one.